# How do you call timestamp() on column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
  time1 = time2 = time3 = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 2, 8, 15)
  rows = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      "id": [1, 1, 1],
      "time": [dt1, dt2, dt3],
    })
```

When I do

```
rows.time.dt.timestamp()
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
```

I can call `timestamp()` on each individual `rows.time.iloc[i]`, but I would like to do it on the whole column.

Comment: @BigBen So in the existing code, there's a call to `rows.time.iloc[i].timestamp()` over the rows. `timestamp()` here seems to convert the current time to seconds since 1970 ish. Instead of looping over each index `i`, I want to apply it to the entire column

Answer (score 2):

You miss understand the difference between a `DatetimeIndex` and individual `datetime` instances.

If you use the `dt` accessor, you have access to certain attributes and methods from `DatetimeIndex` instance. Here `timestamp` is not a method of `DatetimeIndex` but a method of `datetime` instance.

If you want to get the `timestamp` in a vectorized way, use numpy:

```
>>> rows.time.values.astype(float) / 10**9
array([1.6699689e+09, 1.6699689e+09, 1.6699689e+09])
```

Divide by 10**9 because numpy convert the datetime as nanoseconds and timestamp returns a value in seconds.

Comment: yeah just checked. also does `astype(float)` automatically convert the timestamp to POSIX time? that appears to be what it's doing

Comment: Yes. More information here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: I was looking at this documentation just now and it seems this method does not support timezones?

Comment: When I tried this with `rows.time` having timezone info, it gives the error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: You have to use `dt.tz_localize(None)` to remove the timezone information before.